# Using JSON with RFC 3339 full-date in ngModel on input[date]

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, html, date

I have a bunch of `input` fields which I need to populate with data from an WebAPI. The data consist of strings, numbers and dates. The latter is giving me problems.

[HTML5 date input](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.date.html) accepts a [RFC 3339 full-date](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339#section-5.6).

```html
<input type="date" value="2015-01-31">
```

Which is cool and all.

However when using `ngModel` to populate the field [things fall apart](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6630). Basically it says that the value of `ngModel` must be a `Date object`. That's rather unfortunate. Because that means I can't do the following.

```
// jsonData.someDate is a RFC 3339 full-date

// controller
function MyController($scope, jsonData) {
    $scope.data = jsonData;
}

// view
<input type="date" ng-model="data.someDate">
```

Instead I'll have to do something like

```
// controller
function MyController($scope, jsonData) {
    jsonData.someDate = new Date(jsonData.someDate);
    $scope.data = jsonData;
}
```

That's terrible! So I'm looking for the best/easiest way to not having to do that.